# Jhipster with production profile

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, production-environment, production

I have built my jhipster application in production version(frontend app), it did minify all the javascript files and html files, I can see that inside the war, and I run the application in production version too as after completely starting it says jhipster started and the profile has swagger, prod. But when I access my application there is little source folder that gets created and that exposes all of my javascript code as javascript is not minified, over there.
what is this folder?
Why does this folder exists?
how do I disable this folder?
[Link to the screenshot](https://ibb.co/m7ykkb)

Comment: Yes, I have done a clean build and tried loading it from another PC, in another Browser, and i have not configured workspace in chrome, the source shows up in IE Edge as well :(,

Comment: You should probably disable source maps in gulp/build.js also gulp-uglify uses default options which you may want to change.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the source mapping, from the build.js, I though in prod mode the source mapping gets automatically disabled, I guess they just have it to give us option of running the production build in dev profile as well, anyway thank you, go ahead and add this as answer to this question i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably disable source maps in gulp/build.js also gulp-uglify uses default options which you may want to change.